# How to extract jpg EXIF metadata from a folder in chronological order

Tags: python, exif

I am currently writing a script to extract EXIF GPS data from a folder of jpg images. I am using os.scandir to extract the entries from the folder but from my understanding os.scandir opens the files in an arbitrary way. I need the images to be opened in chronological order by filename. Below is my current code which works as intended however it does not open the images in the correct order. The files within my image folder are named chronologically like so: "IMG_0097, IMG_0098" etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, exif, folium

def convert_lat(coordinates, ref):
    latCoords = coordinates[0] + coordinates[1] / 60 + coordinates[2] / 3600
    if ref == 'W' or ref == 'S':
        latCoords = -latCoords
    return latCoords

coordList=[]
map = folium.Map(location=[51.50197125069916, -0.14000860301423912], zoom_start = 16)

from exif import Image
with os.scandir('gps/') as entries:
    try:
        for entry in entries:   
            img_path = 'gps/'+entry.name
            with open (img_path, 'rb') as src:
                img = Image(src)            
                if img.has_exif:
                    latCoords = (convert_lat(img.gps_latitude, img.gps_latitude_ref))
                    longCoords = (convert_lat(img.gps_longitude, img.gps_longitude_ref))
                    coord = [latCoords, longCoords]
                    coordList.append(coord)
                    folium.Marker(coord, popup=str(coord)).add_to(map)
                    folium.PolyLine(coordList, color =" red", weight=2.5, opacity=1).add_to(map)
                    print(img_path)
                    print(coord)
                else:
                    print (src.name,'has no EXIF information')
    except:
        print(img_path)
        print("error occured")

map.save(outfile='/home/jamesdean/Desktop/Python scripts/map.html')
print ("Map generated successfully")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort a list using the built-in `sorted` function, Paul made an interesting point and simply sorting without any arguments will work just as fine:

```
a = ["IMG_0097.jpg", "IMG_0085.jpg", "IMG_0043.jpg", "IMG_0098.jpg", "IMG_0099.jpg", "IMG_0100.jpg"] 
sorted_list = sorted(a)
print(sorted_list)
```

Output:

```
['IMG_0043.jpg', 'IMG_0085.jpg', 'IMG_0097.jpg', 'IMG_0098.jpg', 'IMG_0099.jpg', 'IMG_0100.jpg']
```

In your case you can do:

```
for entry in sorted(entries):
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, would there be a way to automatically extract the filenames into list a? I have tried to do this however when executing the print(sorted_list) I am met with the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0164.jpg'"

here is the code i used:

`from exif import Image
with os.scandir('gps/') as entries:
  for entry in entries: 
   img_path = 'gps/'+entry.name
   filename.append(img_path)
   sorted_list = sorted(filename, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1]))
print(sortedList)`

Comment: You can do this: `a = [i.name for i in entries]`

Comment: For the error i updated the code try it now.

Comment: I have updated the list to now be ` filename= [i.name for i in entries]` however i do not see a change in your code, i still get the same error. after printing.

Comment: I added another split: sorted_list = `sorted(a, key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]))`

Comment: Apologies, I used your updated code however now i am met with the error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Store'"

Comment: Do you have any other files other than image `IMG_XXXX.jpg` in the same directory?

Comment: I do not, there are only .jpg images within the directory. Within the directoy are 69 .jpg images

Comment: Ran it: AttributeError: 'posix.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: Typo sorry: `a = [i.name for i in entries if not i.name.startswith('.')]`

Comment: It worked! however now i cannot get the for loop to execute anymore. I will try again in the morning it is very late here. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You're welcome, since you're creating a new list you can iterate over it `for entry in a:`

Comment: Wow this also worked, thank you so much. You have solved my issue that ive spend many a day trying to fix. I cant thank you enough

Comment: Your welcome, if you need any more help just let me now, also consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would say ditch `os.scandir` and take advantage of more modern features the standard library has to offer:

```
from pathlib import Path
from operator import attrgetter

# assuming there is a folder named "gps" in the current working directory...
for path in sorted(Path("gps").glob("*.jpg"), key=attrgetter("stem")):
    print(path) # do something with the current path
```

The `from operator import attrgetter` and `key=attrgetter("stem")` are a bit redundant, but I'm just being explicit about what attribute I would like to use for determining the sorted order. In this case, the "stem" attribute of a path refers to just the name of the file as a string. For example, if the current path has a filename (including extension) of `"IMG_0097.jpg"`, then `path.stem` would be `"IMG_0097"`. Like I said, the stem is a string, so your paths will be sorted in lexicographical order. You don't need to do any conversion to integers, because your filenames already include leading zeroes, so lexicographical ordering should work just fine.